# Setting date format in Sheetjs while creating a worksheet

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, date-formatting, sheetjs

We have a requirement where we need to download an excel sheet, which has dates as values.The dates need to be formatted in 'mm/dd/yyyy'. Excel does have this option using Format Cells and selecting Date from the categories. But how do we set it before writing the data to a xlsx file? 
We tried using the ['z'] property of the worksheet object, but that creates a custom format which has issues while uploading the same file with changes.

Comment: So you want it to be formatted as values but also want "/" in the field, it doesn't really make sense. Why do you need as values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for writing [excel with date formatting](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx-yydjps?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
data: any = [
    {
      eid: "e101",
      ename: "ravi",
      date: "02/02/2011"
    },
    {
      eid: "e102",
      ename: "ram",
      date: "02/02/2014"
    },
    {
      eid: "e103",
      ename: "rajesh",
      date: "02/02/2016"
    }
  ];

constructor(private excelService: ExcelService) {
    this.data[0].date = this.getDate();
  }
exportAsXLSX(): void {
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.data, "sample");
  }

  getDate(): string {
    var today = new Date();
    let dd = today.getDate();
    let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    let nmm, ndd;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
      ndd = "0" + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
      nmm = "0" + mm;
    }
    return dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Chanaka but this is still not the solution. When the cell with the date is selected, it is formatted as a string and not a date in the stackblitz example. We're able to set the value as a date by modifying the properties 'z', 'w' and 't' by looping through the worksheet. By doing this even though the cell is displayed in mm/dd/yyyy format (example 05/27/2020) But when the cell is in edit mode, the value comes along with a timestamp, like 27/05/2020  12:00:10 AM which is in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format instead of mm/dd/yyyy.